# Viewing only one message as original HTML in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

In Mozilla Thunderbird I have `View`, `Message Body` set to either "`Plain text`" or to "`Simple HTML`" for security reasons.

[image]

Occasionally I would like to view a particular message as "`original HTML`". But the problem is remembering to change this global setting back afterwards.

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or similar convenient way) of viewing only the *current* message as "`Original HTML`" without affecting the global settings?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have found is to install a Thunderbird Add-on named "Allow HTML Temp".

You then get a button on the status bar "original HTML" which you click on for an individual message without affecting other messages

[image: Image of Thunderbird Add-ons Manager showing Allow HTML Temp]